# SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0 - Ionic 2 Http GET request

Tags: javascript, php, json, angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to perform a `GET` request and retrieve the data from the response.

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:8888/maneappback/more-items.php').subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res.json());
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I am getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0`. I am also assuming that the error is related to the request.

On my server side, I have the data being sent like this (PHP):

`echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: seems it's not valid JSON. Have you checked your network tab?

Comment: also `console.log(res.json())` is probably wrong; it's not going to be a function.

Comment: @AJT_82 I looked at the network tab for more-items.php and the response looks like this: `mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 4
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 24
    [type] => 0
)
["\/9j\/4AAQSk................` - the last number is the blob that i am trying to send via the json.

Comment: Well that's clearly not JSON.

Comment: Just a Pointy said... there is something funky going on in your db-request. Better check the php code, since that is not correct :)

Comment: I think I figured it out...i had print statements in my backend that i wasnt seeing...thanks for pointing me in the right direction so far

Comment: @AT82 In my network tab with `res.json()` I get `Oops, an error in the gateway has occurred. If the issue persists, please contact support@rapidapi.com`. Without `res.json()`, the response object has `'content-type' => 'application/json'..status: 500..body: { stream: undefined }` and no error occurs. But I do not see the content.

Comment: @AT82 Regarding my comment three hours ago, I had the wrong hostname in `'x-rapidapi-host'` header. Removing the `https://` at the beginning - which is though used in url - solved it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was just neglecting to realize that I still had two `echo` statements in the script...that is why it wasn't recognized as JSON.

Comment: I had the same issue as well; I had not removed some other echo when i echoed the json.

Answer (score 13):

The message you see is that your JSON response is not formatted correctly

**GOOD JSON:**

```
{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }
```

**BAD JSON**

```
    { 'name': 'john' }
    { name: "john" }
```

**OR**

```
{ 'name' = 'john' }
```

In your case, the JSON begins with character C
keep in mind that a valid Javascript object could be invalid JSON form

Answer (score 2):

in my case:

previous with error: `JSON.parse("{ createdTimestamp: -1 }")`

and correct: `JSON.parse('{"createdTimestamp":-1}')`