# SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0 in app.js

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

Here is the code:
I am getting an error saying :SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0 but this occurs sometimes.

```js
function fetchData(user_country) {
  fetch(`https://covid19-monitor-pro.p.rapidapi.com/coronavirus/cases_by_days_by_country.php?country=${user_country}`, {
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "0eb507ba94mshbdcee33e20f63e2p1f00eajsn1967cf2bd741",
        "x-rapidapi-host": "covid19-monitor-pro.p.rapidapi.com"
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxError: Unexpected token C in JSON at position 0 - Ionic 2 Http GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348556/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-c-in-json-at-position-0-ionic-2-http-get-request)

Answer (score 1):

The response returned by your API is not in a parsable JSON format. First, console.log the `response` to see what you are getting

And then you can covert it into JSON